# Getting value from an input in html using python

Tags: python, html

So, I'm making a program in python that is executed when the user gives values in an input in HTML. Everything runs OK.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # parsing
r = open("C:/Python27/Pruebas/pruebahtml.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"html.parser")
R4sem = soup.find("input",attrs={'id':'R4sem'})["value"]
R5sem = soup.find("input",attrs={'id':'R5sem'})["value"]
r.close()

txt = open('C:/Python27/Pruebas/Pruebaconfigfechas.txt','w')

Encabezado = """Due-Date-Function "DD_General" 
Type PiecewiseConstant 
Multiplier 1 
Calculation-Policy Time-Relative 
DueDate-Policy FODuedateToBucketEndTime 
Attribute "FechaTope" \n"""
fechar4 = "\nDATE -4 weeks Score "
fechar5 = "\nDATE -5 weeks Score "

txt.write(Encabezado+fechar4+R4sem+fechar5+R5sem)
txt.close()
```

But when checking the new text file, R4sem and R5sem are empty. So my question is, I can't read the values that the inputs have or there's another way to do this. The users are gonna be usin the HTML constantly so the values are gonna be changing, so I thought that using inputs would be the best solution.

If needed I can put also the HTML code I have.

EDIT: Here's the HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>*AJAW*</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Penalidadeshtml v0.1.3</p>

<div>
<form action="file:///C:/Python27/Pruebas/dist/lectura.exe">
  Retraso 4 sem: <input type="text" name="R4sem" id="R4sem" value=""><br>
  Retraso 5 sem: <input type="text" name="R5sem" id="R5sem" value=""><br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Grabar">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's a silly question: How are the users putting the values in the pruebahtml.html file?  Is this a file that they see served to them from a web server and type the values into the R4sem and R5sem fields as presented in their browser, or are they actually editing the HTML file itself?

Comment: this looks like a phishing script with two reserved fields for username/email and password.

Comment: The html file can be run in an application we have (I can't say more because of my company), but you can see it exactly as if you were using any web browser. They see the form where the input boxes are and the button that starts and .exe with this code.

Comment: I have to add more input boxes, but all the data that is gonna be inputted are just numbers.

Comment: why dont you use php, @JoshuaCazares?

Comment: I don't know about php, but the only kind of file the program can read is html (and it seems that also asp, but I'm not sure).

Comment: So the program you're using reads the HTML file from disk, presents it to the users to type the values in, and then saves it back in the same place as HTML but with the data entered into the DOM also serialized?  You're going to need to post that sample of the HTML...

Comment: I am thinking if I can make an script, put the value in variables, and then get them with python. Can it be done that way?

Comment: In the example HTML you posted, there are no values in the R4sem and R5sem fields.  So, first job, if you're parsing the values out of those fields with BS4, is to get some values into them!

Comment: When I edit the HTML and put values in the fields then your python code w/ bs4 picks them up quite happily.

Comment: Yeah, but The user is gonna be putting those values, so that's my question, can you get the values the user in putting in??

Comment: You're going to have to do some "book learnin'" on how web technologies work, and how your company's web browser program works specifically. When users fill in the details on a web form, their responses aren't (generally) saved back to the source file itself - which is what you're parsing with bs4.  Instead their responses are POSTed back to the URL in the action of the form - in this case "lectura.exe". That program needs to be able to handle that response.  You might want to read up a bit on the (rather old fashioned) CGI (Common Gateway Interface) programming model - it might help?

Comment: In that case, is it possible to use other html editor to this task, like in ASP or VB??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved this by creating the text file I needed in the HTML, so it was easier to send the values the user put and have the document I was asked to deliver.

Thanks for the comments.